# activity stack auto clearing?

Tags: android, android-activity, stack

I have classes A, B, C, D; and they are done one after the other. When i get to class D then hit the back button it goes to class B (class C i have as a not history in the manifest) but instead of staying on class B from D, it goes back to class A after about a second all by itself.

why would it do that, how would you even debug something like that because the logcat does not say anything when it happens.

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd write some Log.d code like:

Log.d("MY_TAG", "Activity A, B C or D onCreate");

in every activity's onStart(), onCreate(), onResume(), onPause(), onStop() and on Destroy()

Then filter the logcat on MY_TAG

and see if that helps you track it down.